# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown menu not fitting the width of content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm havng this small problem with my dropdown menu. 
I need the width fit the content inside the content

In my css I'm using

```
width: -ms-max-content;
width: -webkit-max-content;
width: -moz-max-content;
width: -o-max-content;
```

But it´s not working on IE, is there another method for doing this?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have any link to your project or a fiddle?

Comment: Sort of, a few things are not showing, like font awesome icons, some images... but pretty much you can check the chat here: http://jsfiddle.net/yno8ywys/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `pull-left` classes on your images, then it will work without having to use `max-content`.

[**Working Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/nAicsE67BE)

Comment: worked amazing. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this code?

```
ul li a{
   white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: it breaks the words but I wish it could stay in the same line if possible

Comment: Also I can't set a min-width because I don't know the length of the names in that list. Thanks